# How to hide someone else's directories from a user?

Tags: permissions, chmod, chown

I have several folders:

```
/home/user1/ -u user1 -G user1
/home/user2/ -u user2 -G user2
/home/user3/ -u user3 -G user3
```

I created three users user1, user2, user3. Each user has their own group. Any user can see other account folder for a while but cannot open it.

After user2 logged in using ssh they shouldn't see any folders downto its folder `/home/user2/`.
They should see only folders in `/home/user2/`.

How to set these permissions?

Answer (score 4):

If you use `chmod` to set only set the x bit for `group` and `other` on /home - This disallows reading `/home` (`ls` will fail on /home), but the `x` bit allows traversal to known sub-directories.

And also set no access for `group` and `other` on sub-directories in `/home` ie the user directories.

If you are the user root, the commands would be:

```
chmod go=x /home 
chmod go-rwx /home/user[123]
```

Then user2 will only be able to see the files in user2's home directory and `ls` on /home, /home/user1 and /home/user3 will fail; *ls: cannot open directory 'directory-name': Permission denied*

Comment: This way, the users won't be able to list directories in /home (which requires read permission on /home, which you're revoking assuming sane ownership), but **it won't prevent them from knowing about those directories** because all users' home directories are likely named in /etc/passwd, which is world readable.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Yes, but there is no good way around that, apart from making `/etc/passwd` unreadable for users. The OP requested the directories "not to be seen", which this accomplishes.

Comment: @peterph True, but I still think it's an important caveat. Whether or not it is *important* depends on the exact use case.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling sure - actually the requirement is quite strange - there are lots of ways to get names (and the likely location of their home directories) of at least some users on a system.

Comment: `chmod go-rwx /home/*` worked in my case. You might have to use `sudo` for permission to run the command.

Answer (score 1):

It depend on system that you use.

There are many MAC implementations, [Mandatory Access Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandatory_access_control).

FreeBSD famous for its MAC. (see [handbook](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/mac.html))

Look at OpenBSD's [systrace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systrace), its wrapper around shell give you a total control over what user can or can not do and see.

Linux rejoices by large of amount such systems. Look at [SELinux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux), [AppArmor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppArmor), see also [Grsecurity patch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grsecurity)...

The easiest way and most popular is to put user into chroot(Linux), lxc-container(Linux), jail(FreeBSD), and many more...